# Ruling on Fiverr's (freelance platform) commission for a permanent client

Tags: halal-haram

I and my brother worked online as the freelance developers through Fiverr.

I gave an interview to a client in November/December 2020 for my brother and myself in which I mentioned that we will both work for the client. Back then I was working on another job. I tried to work for the client but I could not work with him until April 2021 because I could not manage two jobs. Then, I decided all terms and conditions of my work with the client directly on whatsapp at the end of March.

Fiverr mentions in their terms and conditions that all communications and money should only go through their platform on which they charge around 20%. My mother said to get payments directly from the client from now on because the client is permanent now and we have already paid a lot of commission to Fiverr monthly so there is no need to pay anymore.

My question is that is it permissible if I get the payments directly from client instead of getting through Fiverr? I work for the client on monthly basis and do I have to keep paying a hefty amount to Fiverr each month? Fiverr's headquarters are also located in Israel so I don't want to do business with them. Can I close my account on Fiverr and get the money from the client directly because I would no longer be obliged to their terms and conditions?

JazakAllah

Comment: I used Fiverr lots of time years ago. How do you get the email or contact info of your employer/client on Fiverr? Is it within Fiverr chat or somewhere else? If you get the client's email or phone somewhere else, then it is not against the Fiverr terms, so it is not haram, even though you knew the client the first time via Fiverr. If the client tries to tell his email within the Fiverr chat, the Fiverr system itself won't allow that and will block his message. Please edit your question and add the details.

Comment: @AhmedYousef We sent the buyer request and in response, the buyer sent the zoom link in the chat for the interview and where he asked for the WhatsApp number

Comment: @AhmedYousef That's not true, the Fiverr system only issues a notice saying that no contact information should be shared UNLESS IT IS A REQUIREMENT FOR THE PROJECT.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is good. But both parties should agree i.e you and your client. It is totally permissible.
The other thing which you mentioned about Israel. Then using there product does not mean you are supporting them. However avoiding is best option. So go for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also asked the imams of two Masjids and one of them said there is no issue with direct payment. The other told me not to take it. But, once I mentioned that the other imam permitted it then he said okay fine. But, there is something in my heart. I don't know what should I do really! Then, sometimes I asked to different people on different platforms and got no response to my questions. I am very much confused about what should I do. Because this is a very serious matter to which everyone is answerable to Allah for.

Comment: Look brother Fiverr is just a medium between you and your client. Just talk to your client about this issue. If he agrees on direct payment. Then there is no problem, as both parties are willingly doing this.

Comment: I really thank you for trying to answer my question. I did not receive the answer on any platform I have tried to ask this questions, although I asked my friends and family and almost all of them say that there is no problem with direct payments Islamically. I asked the client as you mentioned and the client insists that He wants to pay without Fiverr. But, my question stands whether fiverr have a right of commission in the payment or not since the client is permanent sort of. Do I have to keep paying to fiverr after I paid them once?

Comment: Also if the client is not even agreeing and willing to pay through fiverr. Am I free of this burden and responsibility?

Comment: Please add some references to support your answer as well. I myself do not agree with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

They can hire you for an immediate work, called a "Gig" (fyi, I am a marketplace facilitator like fivver).

> #### Confidentiality
>
> Sellers should recognize that there might be a need for Buyers to disclose certain confidential information to be used by Sellers for the purpose of delivering the ordered work, and to protect such confidential information from unauthorized use and disclosure. Therefore, Sellers agree to treat any information received from Buyers as highly sensitive, top secret and classified material. Without derogating from the generality of the above, Sellers specifically agree to (i) maintain all such information in strict confidence; (ii) not disclose the information to any third parties; (iii) not use the information for any purpose except for delivering the ordered work; and (vi) not to copy or reproduce any of the information without the Buyer’s permission.

You aren't in violation of Fivver's terms of service, even. The buyer of your work is, however, if they are hiring you for the first time themselves.

> Please respect our members privacy by not contacting them with offers, questions, suggestions or anything which is not directly related to their Gigs or orders. Users may not submit proposals or solicit parties introduced through Fiverr to contract, engage with, or pay outside of Fiverr.

The full measure of their ordinary profit is fine but not to contract labor.

> You must not be against writing ˹contracts˺ for a fixed period—whether the sum is small or great. This is more just ˹for you˺ in the sight of Allah, and more convenient to establish evidence and remove doubts. However, if you conduct an immediate transaction among yourselves, then there is no need for you to record it, but call upon witnesses when a deal is finalized. Let no harm come to the scribe or witnesses. If you do, then you have gravely exceeded ˹your limits˺. (2:282)

Answer (score 0):

I work in fiverr, actually just like many users I didn't read their terms and conditions before signing up. I did have some regular clients at that site who later on contacted me directly to do their work. I didn't think much about and worked directly with them, so I can save 20% commission. My thinking was that we have to give them commission only if we are using their platform for communication or uploading files. Just because I met a client in fiverr doesn't meant we should never meet directly in different platform or directly in person or email. Nobody can create such a terms and condition, even if they do, I don't think it will be legally binding in any court of law.